# What is the fundamental difference between heat and electricity?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electrons

When I had some basics of physics in high school, I learned from my teacher this:

> There are two types of energy transfer - heat and work. If the heat is reflected in a temperature change, it is heat. Otherwise, it is work.

It is well known that there are many analogies between voltage and temperature, and the vibrations give the transfer of heat and current in the lattice. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If we take a solid material with two different boundary sources, heat and electricity, I imagine that heat makes the entire lattice vibrate, but there is no electron transfer. On the other hand, I imagine that electricity is only between electrons. Is this correct? I have sketched something to visualize my interpretation (the squiggly lines represent vibration):

[image]

Is this interpretation correct or there is more to it? Can anyone help me to understand the fundamental difference between these two means of energy transportation?

I have to mention that I don't have a clear interpretation of electrical energy. Are the electrons moving within a material or they just transmit energy by vibration?

Any help or reference suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's anything massively wrong with your interpretation as far as it goes. 1) Heat and Electricity are both forms of energy transfer and as such are, I would say, "fundamentally" the same. 2) There is coupling between them, electricity/electrons interact with the lattice this is call electrical resistance. Heat can result in changes to electrical properties dependent on the material, such as thermistors and thermoelectrics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found it an important issue to understand electricity and heat.